# How do I make apache2.4 configuration specific to a particular virtualhost so it doesn't affect other virtualhost on a centos server

Tags: linux, centos, vps, apache2.4

I have put in my include file which is in this directory /etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/myusername/sub.domain.com/proxy.conf.

On the file I did proxy reverse to localhost port 5000 for my net core app.
Then I did a post virtualhost include using include editor.

When I try to reach other domain on same VPS I get server temporarily unavailable to handle request error.but when I uncommented the proxy reverse on my include file i was able to reach other domain.

So my question is given the procedure I have taken, why is an include specified for a particular virtualhost affecting other virtualhosts on the server.

Proxy reverse code in the include file is code below

````
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/ ```

And this include was applied to virtualhost for the particular sub domain, don't know why it affects other virtualhosts.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i did was i opened up the post_virtualhost_global.conf file found in /etc/apache2/includes/.

then i removed the include statement from the post_virtualhost_global.conf file, then it worked, i dont seem to understand how, but it worked perfectly anyway. i have also applied same practice for subsequent virtualhost proxyreverse includes i have done afterward.

Answer (score 0):

> Then I did a post virtualhost include using include editor.

If this means outside the `<virtualhost>` then its no wonder it affects all virtualhosts -- outside of `<virtualhost>`  is global.

Comment: when i added the virtualhost tag, i got an error that i cant have virtualhost inside virtualhost. the include only worked when i removed the virtualhost tag. However i have solved the issue and would post the answer below.